# Declaring and changing the data in a C string based on conditions?

Tags: c

There are 3 types of food orders: Fish, Chips, Drink. The user is prompted for what they want to order, the template for the question is as follows:

```
Do you order ___ (Y/N)? -  
___ choice (food options):   
What size (L-Large, M-Medium, S-Small):   
How many orders do you want? (>=0):  
You ordered ___  SIZE:     order number:    subtital: $x.xx
```

So based on the users input, it will be fish, chips, or drink. The program FIRST asks if they want fish first though, so the way I did this (and it works) is the following:

```
main() {
    question("fish");
}
```

question function (what im having trouble with):

```
void question (char choice[]) {

    char choiceYesNo;
    char foodChoice[];
    char foodOptions[];

    switch (choice[0]) {
    case 'f':
        foodChoice[] = "fish";
        foodOptions[] = "(K - Haddock, T - Halibut)";
        break;
    case 'c':
        // options for chips
        printf("Do you order CHIPS? (Y/N): \n");
        break;
    case 'd':
        // options for drinks
        printf("Do you order DRINK? (Y/N): \n");
        break;
    }

    printf("Do you order %c? (Y/N): \n", toupper(foodChoice));
        scanf("%c", choiceYesNo);
    printf("%c choice %c: \n", foodChoice, foodOptions);
        scanf("%c", foodSelect);
    printf("What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): \n");
        scanf("%c", foodSize);
    printf("How many orders do you want? (>=0): \n");
        scanf("%c", foodOrders);
    printf("You ordered %c: %c - SIZE: %c   amount ordered: %d, subtotal price: %.2lf\n", toupper(foodChoice), foodSize, foodOrders, foodSubtotal);

}
```

What works in my question function is the part where the switch selects f, c, or d, that's fine. What I don't understand is that when it picks f, it should set foodchoice to "fish", and foodOptions to their correct options based on that food so that instead of just having that huge printf and manually filling it per each case in the switch, I can just save the time and effort and use variables to fill it in, but I can't get it working :P Then I have to use pointers which I'll tackle later to process the user input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to call question exactly in this way (string literal as the argument), you don't have to allocate any memory, just use char* for foodChoice. The assignment and only an assignment will work this way. It you need to concatenate strings, use strncpy or memcpy. For that you need statically or dynamically allocated buffer.

Also note that you can't do

```
char array[];
array = "string";
```

, because the compiler has to know exact size of the array at compile time. The only thing you can do is

```
char *string;
string = "string";
```

or

```
char array[] = "string";
```

, because the latter one is in fact

```
char array[7] = "string";
```

, which is in fact

```
char array[7] = { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
```

For more about arrays vs pointers check [arrays vs pointers](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing memory allocation and not correctly copying the choice strings:

```
char foodChoice[1024]; // or dynamically:
char *foodOptions = malloc(1024);

switch (choice[0]) {
case 'f':
    strcpy(foodChoice, "food");
    strcpy(foodOptions, "(K - Haddock, T - Halibut)");
    break; /* ... */
```

Comment: And don't forget to use %s for "strings" and only use %c for chars.